# Roll standalone JBoss app under Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, java, jboss

I've got a Linux box where there’s Tomcat running, with some JSP applications in it. Now, I’ve received a third party app from a developer shop to be eventually deployed. It came as an archive called "jboss7.tar" which, it seems, contained a whole standalone Web server. Once I’ve followed their instructions and run the designated shell script, it would start a server that would listen on port 8081, and app pages are being served up.

Still, this strikes me as an inelegant setup. Why run two Web servers side by side, both of them Java-enabled? Also, the manual startup of the standalone app, I don't like that either. The real question is – can I take the user-provided portions from the said archive and somehow plug it under the existing Tomcat instance? It looks like the user code is packaged into files with .war extension, I can see them under /var/jboss7/standalone/deployments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether or not the webapp is using any Java EE feature that is not available in Tomcat (for example, EJBs) and whether it has any JEE or JBoss-specific configuration. Tomcat is not a full-fledged Java EE server, it is just a servlet container. Only way to really know is to either try it or ask the developers.

Comment: Assuming it does not, can't I try and see? I know it has some configuration settings in standalone/configuration/standalone.xml (a MySQL datasource).

Comment: Of course you can give it a try. Check the Tomcat logs and you'll know soon enough if it works.

Comment: How exactly? I've got a file called, say, foo.war. I wanna make a folder `http://mysite/foo/` where it would sit and work. How?

Comment: It depends on how you installed and configured Tomcat, but the easiest way is probably to put the war inside Tomcat's `webapps` directory and then restart Tomcat. You can find plenty of info on the Web on how to deploy a war file in Tomcat.